# How to transpile inline/embedded javascript using babel?

Tags: babeljs

I use "babel" command to transpile ES6 script to ES5.

Ex: `babel testES6.js --out-file testES5.js`

It works fine. My question is how to transpile inline javascript.
For Ex: test.html

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          //ES6 scripts
      </script>
   </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm looking for a way to _precompile_ some HTML files like your example above without relying on the in-browser "standalone" babel script. That is, I want to take a file like yours above and create a new file which has the `<script>` contents transpiled.

Comment: same problem here. using babel-standalone in production is not a solution!

Answer (score 8):

According the [babel docs](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/), it supports scripts typed `text/ecmascript-6` or `text/babel`. Add the browser build into your page and set proper type for your scripts.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code and enjoy :)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">

</script>
```