# Transpile JavaScript within an HTML file to ES5

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, babeljs, transpiler

I have an HTML document that contains a lot of inline JavaScript in script tags and also in other element's attributes (onload, onclick etc).
I need to make that file work in an environment that only supports ES5. The JavaScript however uses a lot of new features that are only available in ES6 and above.

The transpiling has to be triggered using a node.js script (which btw is responsible for generating the HTML file in the first place).

I couldn't really figure out a good way of doing that.

My first idea was:

- Use cheerio to iterate over all the script tags
- use babel to transpile the innerHTML of each tag
- write the transpiled html back to the original script tags

And that works fine, but it completely ignores JavaScript of `onclick` properties etc and probably creates a lot of redundant code because the transpiler is only aware of a small portion of the code at a time.

Simplified example:

```
// npm i cheerio @babel/core @babel/preset-env
const babel = require("@babel/core")
const cheerio = require("cheerio")

const generatedHtml = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="number" id="input1" value="2"></input>
    to the power of
    <input type="number" id="input2" value="6"></input>
    =
    <input type="number" id="result"></input> <br />
    <button onclick="(()=>{document.getElementById('result').value = power(document.getElementById('input1'), document.getElementById('input2'))})()">Calculate</button>

    <script>
      const power = (a,b) => a.value**b.value
    </script>

    <script>
      (async()=>"Hello World")().then(console.log)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
`;

(async()=>{
    const $ = cheerio.load(generatedHtml)
    for (const el of $('script').get()) {
        const originalCode = $(el).html()
        const transpiledCode = (await babel.transformAsync(originalCode, { presets: ["@babel/preset-env"] })).code
        $(el).html(transpiledCode)
    }
    const transpiledHtml = $.html()
    console.log(transpiledHtml)
})().catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transpile inline/embedded javascript using babel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120919/how-to-transpile-inline-embedded-javascript-using-babel)

Comment: @bigless That question is not about using babel as a node module and the provided solution only transpiles very specific script tags, not normal script tags or JavaScript found in element attributes.

Comment: That's one reason why you should not use the `onXXXX` attributes to handle events. They greatly decrease maintainability and lead to many problems like these when the project is becoming larger.  In the long run, you should get rid of these.

Comment: Put your onClick code into the script tags and give the elements ids to bind them to the click event.

Comment: My environment is complicated. It is not a normal browser. I have good reasons to put JS into onXXXX attributes. Basically whenever a script tag contains invalid JS or throws an error, the JS of all script tags stops working. All JS found in attributes continues to work just fine, so certain critical parts have to remain in the onXXXX attributes.

Comment: Dealing with runtime or syntax error that way is still not a good solution it looks more like a workaround. Possible runtime errors can and should be handled with `try-catch` blocks, and if you need to work with dynamic code that might have syntax errors then you should use a linter in the compositing process in a similar way you currently try to use the transpiler. I know that might not be possible do from one day to another, but you really should overthink your design choice.

Comment: Anyway, I don't really understand what your problem with those `on....` attributes is. The same way you search for `script` you could search for all tags having an attribute starting with `on` and then for those tags look for all attributes starting with `on` and use the transpiler for those. And about the `probably creates a lot of redundant code`well there you would need the thing over your design choice and write it all on a script tag or one file. There is no reliable way around that.

Comment: It is not possible to catch syntax errors and linting messes up the performance pretty badly. I already tried that. About your claim "There is no reliable way around that." I honestly doubt that. With all the insane HTML and JS parsers we have, there should be a perfectly reliable way of doing that. I wouldn't even be surprised if there was a node modules that already does it.

Comment: `It is not possible to catch syntax errors` yes that's why I said runtime errors and linting for syntax errors. `linting messes up the performance pretty badly` then you must have done something wrong, a `babel.transformAsync` has to do much more then linting to ensure that transformations are valid and performs syntax validation by parsing the source into an AST before it can do any transformations, so if you do a `babel.transformAsync` anyway, you already know if the code is syntax error free. I hope that you will find a reliable way, even if I doubt it is a good idea.

Comment: Please calm down and stop accusing me of just doing it wrong when you don't even know my application. As I said it is very complicated. There are pre-generated scripts written in ES6 and above that have to be transpiled once. And then there are dynamic scrips that are being created during runtime. And when I do linting on those, the performance drops significantly. But it gets even worse: The bare fact that I now have a few KBs of additional code to deal with is enough to hurt performance in some cases. The environment that I have to deal with just sucks and there is nothing I can do about it.